# How to concatenate all lines of a file from ant script?

Tags: bash, ant

I have a text file in the following format:

```
cat yourfile.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

I want to convert it to:

a,b,c,d,e,f,g

This is the solution I came up to now:

```
while read line; do printf "%s%s" $line "," ; done < yourfile.txt
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,
```

Two issues:

- I am getting an extra comma (,) at the end
- I know I can run this command inside a shell script and exec the shell script from my build.xml. Or there is more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' test.txt 
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191) to read more details.

Otherwise, for the other solutions, it's very easy to remove the final comma. For example with `sed` :

```
$ cat test.txt|tr "\n" ","|sed "s/,$//g" 
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
$ while read line; do printf "%s%s" $line "," ; done < test.txt|sed "s/,$//g" # with your solution
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `tr` command

```
> string=$(tr $'\n' ',' < "yourfile.txt"); echo "${string%,*}"
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

With the bash substitution to remove the trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

A "one"-liner taking advantage of the `IFS` variable and arrays:

```
str=$( IFS=$'\n'; arr=( $(<test.txt) ); IFS=,; echo "${arr[*]}" )
```

First, the entire file is read into an array, using a line-feed as the field
splitter to ensure one line per element. Next, the field separator is changed
to a comma so that the entire array is joined into one comma-delimited string.